# Python - Connect to remote server and find file to scp to local server

Tags: python, file, server, find, scp

Looking for some assistance, fairly new to python and currently trying to figure out the best way to connect to remote server and find latest file like *_CMTS_LOOKUP.csv* and copy to local server.

Here is what I have at the moment....

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, os, re, glob, smtplib, pymsteams, paramiko
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from subprocess import call
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect("x.x.x.x",22,username="xxxxxxxx",password='',timeout=4)
sftp = s.open_sftp()

stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command('find /opt/arris/Daily-ingest/* -name *CMTS_LOOKUP.csv | sort | tail -1') 
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print (line)
    filepath, file = os.path.split(f"{line}")
    
    print (filepath)
    print (file)

cmd = f"scp xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:{filepath}{file} /data/NXT/incoming/{file}"
call(cmd.split(" "))
```

Comment: I'd advise some `try .. except` wrappings.

Comment: I am very new to python and not sure what that is but certainly will google some examples, cheers